# object with value without key as method param

Tags: javascript

I am working with prisma nexus and in the `prismaObjectType` i saw something weird.
A very basic example is this.

simple function, `demo(p)` `p` should be an object

```
            function demo(p) {
              console.log(p);
              console.log(p.normal);
              console.log(p.normal());
            }
```

I am going to pass a key `normal` and a function as value

```
        demo({a:"a", normal: function(){console.log("normal")},b:"b"});
```

It logs in the console

```
            {a: "a", normal: ƒ, b: "b"}
            ƒ (){console.log("normal")}
            "normal"
```

The weird part is that i am passing a method without the word function also without a key

```
            demo({a:"a",   weird(){ console.log("it is weird") }   ,b:"b"});    

            // console

            {a: "a", weird: ƒ, b: "b"}
            ƒ weird(){console.log("it is weird")}
            it is weird
```

`{a:"a",  the weird part >>>>> weird(){console.log("it is weird")} <<< ,b:"b"}`

What is the name of this kind of practice? Any comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is expected JS behavior. It was introduced as shorthand in ecma 2015 ([mdn reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015))

basically:

```
var o = {
  property(parameters) {}
};
```

is short for

```
var o = {
  property: function(parameters) {}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

That's "shorthand" syntax for a function property on an object, [introduced in ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).  Basically, the following two are equivalent:

```
// traditional syntax
const foo = {
    bar: function bar(msg) { console.log(msg); }
};

// shorthand syntax
const foo = {
    bar(msg) { console.log(msg); }
};
```